# Unity Device Location in Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, geolocation, location, latitude-longitude

This is what I have tried, I want an Android device's location (latitude & longitude) but it returns 0, 0.

```
private float userLatitude , userLongitude;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(StartLocation());

    if(!Input.location.isEnabledByUser){
        Screen1ErrorMessage.ShowUserMessage("Location is Disabled.");
    }
}

IEnumerator StartLocation(){
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        Screen1ErrorMessage.ShowUserMessage("Enable Location to Play, else you can't be able to Join any Room");
        yield break;

    Input.location.Start();

    int maxWait = 20;
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        Screen1ErrorMessage.ShowUserMessage("Timeout retrieving device location. Make sure you are connected to the internet");
        yield break;
    }

    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        Screen1ErrorMessage.ShowUserMessage("can't obtain device location, Enable Device Location to Play.");
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        userLatitude = Input.location.lastData.latitude ;
        userLongitude =  Input.location.lastData.longitude;
        isLocationAcquired = true;
        StartCoroutine(StartLocationUpdate());
    }

    Input.location.Stop();
}

IEnumerator StartLocationUpdate()
{
    string url = "--------------------------------------";

    Screen1ErrorMessage.ShowUserMessage("please wait...");

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    form.AddField("UserId", PlayerPrefs.GetString("userId"));
    form.AddField("longitude", userLongitude.ToString());
    form.AddField("latitude", userLatitude.ToString());


    Debug.Log("Updation Location for User:"+PlayerPrefs.GetString("userId")+" : Latitude :" + userLatitude + " Longitude : "+userLongitude);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    var Response = JSON.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);
    if (Response["status"].Value == "true")
        // Screen1ErrorMessage.ShowUserMessage(result.message);
        Debug.Log("User Location Update Success");
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("User Location Update Failed Response ->" + Response.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have called the Coroutine in my start method, should I try on awake also? I'm trying to call another Coroutine based n first's result but it's never gets called. that means there is an issue of location service.

Comment: Where are you calling the StartLocation() from and where are you trying to access the result that shows 0,0?

Comment: I'm Calling StartLocation() in start() method and after successful initialization of userLatitude & userLongitude, I called StartCoroutine(StartLocationUpdate()) which uses both userLatitude & userLongitude global parameter.

Comment: Please the code to your question. It makes it easier to spot the issue

Comment: check it, please.

Comment: looks ok. are you running this from the editor? what happens when you put `Input.location.lastData.latitude` and `Input.location.lastData.longitude` in the update function?

Comment: I tried on my PC and Android Device both had location ON

Comment: Put `Input.location.lastData.latitude` and `Input.location.lastData.longitude` in the Update function then use a simple Text component to display it on the screen. Build on Android and go outside. See if the Text component value changes

Comment: Tried, but still 0,0

Answer (score 0):

The same issue here. I'm using custom android manifest file (build setting->player settings->publishing settings->custom main manifest), so I fixed it by editing my custom manifest file by adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```